# Extend Python list "inline"

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for an alternative to the *list.extend()* method that works inline.

Instead of

```
x = range(15,30,3)
x.extend([0])
print (x)

>>> [15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 0]
```

I need an equivalend that works inline, like

```
print range(15,30,3).extend([0])

>>> None
```

But extend does not return the list itself.

Is there any fancy out-of-the-box commmand to achieve the same?

Comment: Ah, `print sum([range(15,30,3)],[0])` seems to work for my case...

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work.  This doesn't work either ["hi"].extend(["my", "name", "is"]).  It results in None.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just concatenate these lists with `+` operator:

```
range(15, 30, 3) + [0]
```

Or, if you need an iterator and the `list` is huge, use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools
it = itertools.chain(range(15, 30, 3), [0])
```

A quick note: [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) creates a `range` object in Python 3+, which doesn't allow concatenation:

> Ranges implement all of the common sequence operations except
>   concatenation and repetition (due to the fact that range objects can
>   only represent sequences that follow a strict pattern and repetition
>   and concatenation will usually violate that pattern).

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3+, like @vaultah said, range creates `range` object. But you can create `list` from the range object first.

```
x = list(range(15, 30, 3)) + [0]
```